# Why am I getting a self signed certificate error when starting Nodemon in React?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, postgresql, ssl-certificate

I am making a React project to boost my portfolio and I'm using Massive to connect to a Heroku Postgres database. When I start up Nodemon to run my app the server starts up but it doesn't connect to my database and I get this error:

```
{ Error: self signed certificate
    at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1058:34)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:636:8) code: 'DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT' }
```

I've never gotten this error before on my other React applications and I'm at an absolute loss as to how to fix it. If anyone needs to see certain lines of my code I'd be happy to show it. Any help is much appreciated!

EDIT: I didn't want to make my whole app insecure but I figured since I'm just in development it would be okay to put process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0" in my server file and now it works. I'm still confused as to why I'm suddenly getting this error so if anyone else has had this happen to them I'd love to hear about it.

EDIT #2: I got the same problem even after getting a certificate on my actual site. In my other site, I haven't updated some of the dependencies and it doesn't have this error so I compared what dependencies were different and narrowed it down to Massive because that's what I'm using to connect to my database. I downgraded the version and it works now! I will continue to look into how to fix this but for now I'll have to use the 6.1.1 version.

Comment: Glad you figured it out! However, wouldn't it be best practice anyway to not connect to your production database in development? You might accidentally mess stuff up.

Comment: @RobertMoore It probably would be good practice but it's just a little project with 3 tables. Everything is already planned out so there's nothing that can be messed up, at least nothing that can't be fixed with DROP TABLES that is!